# Is my desktop's NIC damaged?

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/325155/desktop-nic-cant-connect-to-switch) has a lot of similarity to my situation.
I have a desktop and a laptop connected to my router, which I use to multiplex the internet provided by the ISP's cable.

However, today my desktop is not connecting via the ethernet interface to my router (showing unidentified ethernet network in the adapter settings page), while my laptop is merrily connecting via both wireless and ethernet port to my router.
The desktop also gets a 169.x.x.x ip address, means it can't get DHCP information.

Is the desktop NIC to be replaced now?

Comment: A 169.254.x.x address comes about after failing to be assigned an IP from DHCP, not DNS. More information about more information about APIPA here: http://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range/1106943#1106943

Comment: Is it the same behaviour for the desktop PC if you plug its network cable into a different port on the router? Just to eliminate the router being the issue. Also ensure your drivers are up to date.

Comment: Have you tried to plug the computer in other port of the router, Or try to usethe laptops cable intead of the desktops? Have you tried to reset the router and pc?

Comment: @adampski: I bypassed the router completely and connected the ISP cable into the desktop. Same problem remained. (Oh btw, the router has a clone mac address of the desktop so its possible to bypass it)